# Frozen water lines, what should I do with my electric hot water heater?

Tags: water-heater

I woke up yesterday (Thursday) morning to frozen water lines.  Left taps open all day and still nothing. I will not be able to get anyone in before Monday or Tuesday to thaw the lines.

I don't know what I should do about my electric hot water tank.

I can hear it clicking on and some other funny noises. I do not know if it is full, half full, or even empty. 
IF I turn of the electric supply will the water in the heater freeze?

If I leave it on and the tank is empty will I burn out the motor?

I do not know what the water IN line looks like or heck even the water OUT line for that matter.... 
I have asked a couple of male neighbours what to do and get 'well either way will be okay'  so not overly helpful ~and no one will drop by!
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What is the temperature where the hot water heater is? The tank is big and insulated and while it will take longer to freeze, if the ambient temperature is below freezing, it will eventually freeze.

When pipes freeze, there is much less water volume so they will freeze much faster. Also, copper is an excellent conductor, so standing water in copper pipes will be very close to the surrounding temp.